# Why can I use GL_QUADS with glDrawArrays?

Tags: opengl

The glDrawArrays document does not mention GL_QUADS in mode.
https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml

But my PC is rendered with `glDrawArrays (GL_QUADS, 0, 4);` the rectangle is drawn. My PC is running on OpenGL 4.3.
Why is this?

Comment: Whats the gl context you're working with? compat? version?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your PC implements the [compatibility profile](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.compatibility.pdf).

However the OpenGL spec is just a spec. Vendors are free to implement other stuff as well to make users happy, for example by supporting legacy software.

Comment: I learned that there is a compatibility mode in OpenGL.thank you.